# CIFS mount at boot doesn't work on Raspberry Pi 3 / Raspbian (buster)

Tags: mount, boot, samba

I've set up a new Raspberry Pi 3 B+ running Raspbian 'buster'.

I've copied the /etc/fstab entries for mounting my Ubuntu 18.04 NAS running Samba from another Raspberry Pi 2 running Raspbian 'stretch':

```
//192.168.1.3/public    /pnjnas/public  cifs    _netdev,rw,auto,users,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/home/pi/.smbcred 0       0
//192.168.1.3/pi        /pnjnas/pi      cifs    _netdev,rw,auto,users,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/home/pi/.smbcred 0       0
//192.168.1.3/Qdownload /pnjnas/Qdownload       cifs    _netdev,rw,auto,users,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/home/pi/.smbcred 0       0
//192.168.1.3/sto       /pnjnas/sto     cifs    _netdev,comment=systemd.automount,rw,auto,users,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/home/pi/.smbcred_sto 0       0
```

What happens on that new Pi is the following:

1. at boot, the Samba shares are not automounted
2. if I manually mount them, I get:

   $ sudo mount -a

   mount error(16): Device or resource busy

after which the shares *are* mounted.

How can I get the automount at boot to work?

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo raspi-config` and then choose `3 Boot Options -> B2 Wait for Network at Boot -> <Yes>`

Comment: This was already configured, and wasn't sufficient. I managed to get on-demand mounting to work using "x-systemd.automount,comment=systemd.automount" in /etc/fstab